# Okta API calls are unauthorized when using react SDK

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, okta, okta-api

I am using OKTA for user management and I am having an issue getting user information back. I have followed the documentation, I have CORS set correctly, enabled app permissions, etc.

If I test using postman I get the data back without a problem. It's only when react makes the api call that a 401 is returned. I have also narrowed down the headers causing the problem `origin` and `referrer`.

I am using [okta/react](https://github.com/okta/okta-auth-js#getuser) I have searched for days and can't figure out what I'm missing. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas?

ReactJS Code

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!authState.isAuthenticated) {
      // When user isn't authenticated, forget any user info
      setUserInfo(null);
    } else {
      oktaAuth
        .getUser()
        .then((info) => {
          setUserInfo(info);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // ToDo: log error
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  }, [authState, oktaAuth]);
```

Request Headers: unAuthorized

```
GET /oauth2/default/v1/userinfo HTTP/2
Host: myHost.okta.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:1234/
Content-Type: application/json
X-Okta-User-Agent-Extended: @okta/okta-react/5.1.1 okta-auth-js/4.8.0
Authorization: Bearer sometoken
Origin: http://localhost:1234
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: myCookie
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
TE: Trailers
```

Request Headers: Success

```
GET /oauth2/default/v1/userinfo HTTP/2
Host: myHost.okta.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/json
X-Okta-User-Agent-Extended: @okta/okta-react/5.1.1 okta-auth-js/4.8.0
Authorization: Bearer sometoken
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: myCookie
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
TE: Trailers
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: As a work around I made the full user profile part of the authToken for always.